# Update the WPF DataGrid Column Header Text via code behind

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How can i change the WPF DataGrid Column Header Text via code behind?
i tried the code below but its not working.

```
this.sampleDataGrid.Columns[0].Header = "New Header"; 
this.sampleDataGrid.Refresh();
```

Comment: Works fine here. is your DataGridColumn using a Template for header?

Comment: Yes.The DataGrid is a customized one.

Answer (score 3):

If your DataGridColumn is a Template then you need to change its Template in code.

```
    var template = new DataTemplate();
    template.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    template.VisualTree.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "New Header");
    dataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderTemplate = template;
```